# Identify the id which called the onclick function One onclick function for different id tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<a class="list-group-item btn-outline-primary " href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home mx-1"></i><span>Home</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#about" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-user mx-1"></i><span>About</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#education" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap mx-1"></i><span>Education</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#publication" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="far fa-newspaper mx-1"></i><span>Publication</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#position" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-briefcase mx-1"></i><span>Positions</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#activities" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mx-1"></i><span>Activities &amp; Research</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#Sholarship" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap mx-1"></i><span>Scholarship</span></a>

<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary mb-1" href="#contract" onclick="RemoveNav()"><i class="fas fa-address-card mx-1"></i><span>Contract Me</span></a>
```

In this Code i Have used One onclick function for different id tag. How can identify that this function call from which id.
Main thing is i want to alert from which id RemoveNav() function is called??

Comment: where `RemoveNav ` defined ? also there is no `id` attribute in `a` given in your code

Answer (score 0):

you should try this..

- You can pass uniq id when function call from `<a href='#about' onClick="RemoveNav('about')"></a>`
- You can get id from javascript function.

That's it..

```js
function RemoveNav(id){
  console.log(id);
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#about" onclick="RemoveNav('about')"><i class="fas fa-user mx-1"></i><span>About</span></a>
         
  <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#education" onclick="RemoveNav('education')"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap mx-1"></i><span>Education</span></a>
  
  <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#publication" onclick="RemoveNav('publication')"><i class="far fa-newspaper mx-1"></i><span>Publication</span></a>
  
  <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#position" onclick="RemoveNav('position')"><i class="fas fa-briefcase mx-1"></i><span>Positions</span></a>

   <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#activities"  onclick="RemoveNav('activities')"><i class="fas fa-user-tie mx-1"></i><span>Activities &amp; Research</span></a>
  

   <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary " href="#Sholarship" onclick="RemoveNav('Sholarship')"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap mx-1"></i><span>Scholarship</span></a>
   
  
  <a class="list-group-item  btn-outline-primary mb-1" href="#contract" onclick="RemoveNav('contract')"><i class="fas fa-address-card mx-1"></i><span>Contract Me</span></a>
```